# Angular template not loading

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

[image: Angular directory and route setup]

My template for route('/') is not loading.
No errors received.
Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you place your 'ngRoute' dependency?

Also do not forget to add the ng-view directive on your index page to render template of the current route into the main layout.

```
<div ng-view>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these suggestion are correct, though try these
1. Check whether you mentioned studyDashboard.html in index.html
2. please hit and check '/ngTables' is working??
3. check whether you have described ngRoute dependency as below

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried templateUrl with a `./` on the route?
Try something like `templateUrl: './components/.../...html' I think it'll work!

Best

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help!
Turns out the bug was in my index.html. I accidentally placed "ng-app" in the  tag rather than the  tag, so the app never even loaded.
I feel so foolish ....
Hopefully this answer will help others